# emacs recompile file while running

Tags: emacs

How do you recompile emacs-lisp scripts from within emacs without problems?  I've tried

```
batch-recompile-direcory
```

, but this causes weird glitches with the recompiled files until I restart emacs.  Is there any way to do this so that no errors are caused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Repeated-Loading.html#Repeated-Loading) page of the GNU Emacs Reference manual taks about reloading files and/or libraries.

You definitely have to explicitey reload the new file with  `M-x load-library`, unless there is another emacs mechanism that forces it to reload the newly byte-compiled function.